# Setting background-position via javascript

Tags: javascript, css

so I am trying to set background position (x,y) coordinates using javascript.

```
function createPuzzlePiece(piece, x, y) {
            piece.classList.add("puzzle-piece");
            piece.style.background-position = ??
        }
```

I am unsure of what to set the background-position to. Would appreciate any help!

Comment: `piece.style.background-position` is a syntax error. A syntax that wouldn't throw an error would be `piece.style['background-position']`. But the correct syntax is `piece.style.backgroundPosition`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put your positions in a `String` :

```
function createPuzzlePiece(piece, x, y) {
    piece.classList.add("puzzle-piece");
    piece.style.backgroundPosition = x+'px '+y+'px';
}
```

If your x & y are in % :

```
function createPuzzlePiece(piece, x, y) {
    piece.classList.add("puzzle-piece");
    piece.style.backgroundPosition = x+'% '+y+'%';
}
```

Comment: It should be `backgroundPosition` not `background-position`

Comment: Oh, I can't believe it went through my brain without sending a warning ! I edited it, sorry.